# How to save a wav file downloaded from s3 to a file

Tags: python, amazon-s3, wav

I have an audio wav file saved in s3. I download it with this code:

```
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3_object = s3.Object(
        bucket_name=bucket_name,
        key=self.s3_key(s3_key),
    ).get()
    audio_data = s3_object['Body'].read()
```

Now I want to save the data to a .wav file so I can read and play it later. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

> Try **[download_file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.download_file)**

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=... , aws_secret_access_key=...)
s3.download_file('your_bucket','k.png','/Users/username/Desktop/k.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want the binary data to a file. For example:

```
with open("somefile.wav", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(audio_data)
```